# Python convert byte to string dictionary as efficiently as possible

Tags: python, string, dictionary, byte

I'm trying to efficiently (quickly) convert a byte file into a dictionary.
So far I've decoded it to str, stripped the { } and made that into a dictionary. But I still get the single string quotes ' so I cannot call the dict by keys. How do I do this?

```
response = b'{"address":"david@gmail.com","username":"david","domain":"gmail.com","md5Hash":"f3c52e5ef3d2b471d0ef51c66c21d10c","suggestion":"","validFormat":true,"deliverable":false,"fullInbox":false,"hostExists":true,"catchAll":false,"gravatar":false,"role":false,"disposable":false,"free":true}'
```

Steps I took so far:

```
print(response.decode("utf-8"))

{"address":"david@gmail.com","username":"david","domain":"gmail.com","md5Hash":"f3c52e5ef3d2b471d0ef51c66c21d10c","suggestion":"","validFormat":true,"deliverable":false,"fullInbox":false,"hostExists":true,"catchAll":false,"gravatar":false,"role":false,"disposable":false,"free":true}



print({response.decode("utf-8").replace("}","").replace("{","")})

{'"address":"david@gmail.com","username":"david","domain":"gmail.com","md5Hash":"f3c52e5ef3d2b471d0ef51c66c21d10c","suggestion":"","validFormat":true,"deliverable":false,"fullInbox":false,"hostExists":true,"catchAll":false,"gravatar":false,"role":false,"disposable":false,"free":true'}
```

But I still cannot call the dict by keys due to the `'`.
I Need this to be quick, low on resources.

Comment: this looks like JSON? It doesn't even represent valid Python dict literals, e.g. `false` instead of `False`. Use the `json` module. what is the source of this?

Comment: My question as well.

Answer (score 2):

Like @juanpa.arrivillaga said just use the `json` module.

Here:

```py
import json
d = json.loads(response)
```

Now the value of `d` is your decoded dict.

Again like @juanpa.arrivillaga said there is no need to use `.decode()`, `json.loads()` can operate on bytes.

Comment: You don't even need to `.decode`, `json.loads` accepts `bytes` objects as well as `str` objects